# How to compute the marginal probability form conditional probabilities in logspace?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, logarithm, arithmetic

Normally the marginal probablity is computed as

$p(x) = \sum_y p(x | y) \cdot p(y) $

Now, suppose I have all these probabilities at the right-hand side in logspace (so as logprobabilities).

How do I do this?!?

Comment: More details might help. The product can be done on the log-scale (by summing logs), but you can't avoid the summation, so unless there's some simplification in your application, you'll need to exponentiate and add.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe I am not searching the right way, but I am a bit suprised I seem to be the only one with this problem...

Comment: It's actually quite common to store and work with probabilities as logs; e.g. google *sum log exp trick*. Or search here on *underflow*.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I am doing it ;-) And it works fine as long as you're dividing/multiplying things of course... Thanks for the pointer to the trick! That might help.

Comment: And just in case anyone stumbles upon this and is working in Python (as I am): http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html